# XSLT: Copy child elements of a complex type only once

Tags: xslt

I have the following input structure:

```
<complexType name="InvoiceType">
  <xs:element name="AdressIn"      type="AdressType"/>
  <xs:element name="AdressOut"     type="AdressType" />
  <xs:element name="Partner"       type="PartnerType" />
  <xs:element name="Date"          type="DateType"/>
</complexType>
```

All the referenced types (AdressType,PartnerType,DateType) are also contained in that document as complex types (besides many other).

What i am trying to do is to copy the types that are used within a "InvoiceType"
to a new document. 
My Problem is, the AdressType is used more then once within InvoiceType, and thus it appears more then once in my new document. How can i prevent that? 
I need something like "if that is already pocessed ->skip" but that is not declarativ... maybe xslt is not the right way to achive this.

Thanx for any help!

Edit:

My XSLT i am using so far looks like that (modified to please the simple example)

```
<xsl:template match="xs:complexType"> 
<xsl:for-each select="./xs:element">      
  <xsl:variable name="elementType"><xsl:value-of select="@type"></xsl:value-of></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name=$elementType]"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am applying that template for the InvoceType. Basically i am going threw its contents, see what types are referenced, look them up in the document via their name and copy them.

Comment: So what are you using so far? Somewhere you need to eliminate duplicates, whether that can be done with `distinct-values`, with grouping or simply by using `/.` to eliminate duplicates depends on what you have so far to output the types. Show us the relevant XSLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<xsl:for-each select="./xs:element">      
  <xsl:variable name="elementType"><xsl:value-of select="@type"></xsl:value-of></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name=$elementType]"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

use

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name=current()/xs:element/@type]"/>
```

or define a key

```
<xsl:key name="complex-types" match="xs:schema/xs:complexType" use="@name"/>
```

and then you can use

```
<xsl:copy-of select="key('complex-types', xs:element/@type)"/>
```

Comment: I just tried both ways but could not get it to work. Nothing gets printed out. Just to be sure, i am supposed to place the lines within the complexType template i posted above, right?

Comment: If the previous code worked then yes, replace the `for-each` inside the template with that code. But your input snippet does not seem to be complete and that way it is hard to post a testable suggestion, you might want to post a minimal but complete schema together with a minimal but complete stylesheet outputting the duplicated types, then I am sure I can, if needed, adjust the answer.

Comment: wow, its working! Had to fix the path. Thank you very much! But tbh, i still do not get which part of that expression is responsible for "eleminating" the duplicates... but anyway, thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: Path expressions selecting nodes do eliminate duplicates https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#id-path-operator "If every evaluation of E2 returns a (possibly empty) sequence of nodes, these sequences are combined, and duplicate nodes are eliminated based on node identity. ". And `key` does that, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#func-key, "The result of the function is a sequence of nodes, in document order and with duplicates removed".