# XSLT missing linebreaks when selecting nodes by path expression

Tags: xslt

I am copying some nodes according to [XSLT: Copy child elements of a complex type only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221817/xslt-copy-child-elements-of-a-complex-type-only-once) by using a path expression within a copy-of tag:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name=current()/xs:element/@type]"/>
```

In the output all linebreaks are missing at the elements processed by this statement. (Elesewhere they are shown) It looks like this:

```
...</xs:complexType><xs:complexType....
```

I can only add linebreaks before and after, but not between them. How can i achive this? Thanx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided too little data to attempt any testing. E.g. it is not clear, what output method uses your script.

Quite often XSLT script contains `xsl:strip-space` instruction, which causes normalization of text nodes.
This normalization a.o. changes "internal" sequences of "white" chars, **including line breaks**,
into a single space.

Maybe this is the cause.

Take alse a look at `xsl:output` instruction in your script.
Does it contain `indent="yes"` attribute?
If it doesn't, the output contains no line breaks between output elements.

Maybe your script contains in some places output of explicite line breaks
(e.g. `<xsl:text>&#aA;</xsl:text>`), so these line breaks **are** rendered.

But if you have no `indent="yes"` attribute, then no line breaks are inserted
"automatically" between consecutive elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression only selects the `xs:complexType` elements, not the whitespace that separates them.

When you're working with a vocabulary such as XSD that doesn't use mixed content (except perhaps in annotations) it's probably best to remove all whitespace text nodes from the input using `xsl:strip-space` and then to generate new whitespace in the output using `xsl:output indent='yes'`.